# Visual Studio - Blazor Server projects ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-server-side

All my blazor server projects do not open anymore. Google Chrome gives error: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

- I uninstalled my anti-virus, did not solve the problem
- I tried Windows Internet Connections / Network Troubleshooters
- Removed .vs folder did not solve the problem
- No Windows or Visual Studio updates available
- I deleted all domain security policies in Chrome (chrome://net-internals/#hsts)
- I disabled Windows Defender Firewall
- I used TCP view:

[image: TCP View result]

I am out of options... Anyone who knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: With tcp iew you can check if a port is open and listening, this would be the first I would do

Comment: @nbk I added a screenshot with the TCP view results. Port 7104 is showing multiple times, all with different results. Any advice?

Comment: Are you in an workplace/enterprise? Could their be some proxy killing the SignalR traffic?

Comment: @cjb110 I am using my private laptop. I did not change any settings before or after the problem occurred

Comment: Restart the computer, as there are too many instances running

Comment: @nbk restarted the computer. TCP View is showing only one instance now. But I am still getting the same error (see above for screenshot)